# Laravel ajax return excel instead of binary string

Tags: excel, ajax, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm using laravel. I tried to create an Excel file, and add data into it and download (export) it as Excel file to the client.

But instead of an Excel file being downloaded, it returns a string.

Can someone help me please?

Thanks in advance.

My controller code

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;
public function exportreport(Request $request){
 $file = "users.xlsx";  
 return Excel::download(new reportExport, $file);
}
```

my export code

```
use App\cqqueryformModel;
    class reportExport implements FromCollection
    {
        public function collection(){      
                return cqqueryformModel::all();
            }
    }
```

Return is string instead of the Excel file:

[image]

Console log:

[image]

[console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bU0kk.png)

Comment: You can 't download a excel via a ajx. Just open a new tab with the route and then it will download the excel

Comment: show us the ajax call

Comment: $.ajax({
 
   url: "{{ url('/cqreportModel/exportreport') }}",
     type: 'GET',
     data: {
     account: account,
     rStatus: rStatus,
     rfrom: rfrom,
     rto: rto,
     rtop: rtop

     } ,
   }).done(function (data) { 
      console.log(data);

     if (data.error) {
       showMessage('error','Please fill out all filter fields!');
     }else{
    
     }
       
   
   }).fail(function (data) {
     console.log('Failed');
     showMessage('error','Please check you connection!');
   });

Comment: i get the idea and try it on addess and it download the file

Comment: thanks
now i will research on "laravel ajax open new tab with the get route"
thanks again

Answer (score -2):

Thanks @Nipun it works.

```
 .done(function (data) {         
              var url = "{{ url('/cqreportModel/exportreport') }}";
                    window.open(url, "_blank"); 
             })
```